# Upgrading Spring and Hibernate, HibernateTemplate equals null and ClassCastExceptions

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have been trying to upgrade to the latest version of spring and hibernate. I've been having huge troubles getting everything to work properly.

I am using Java Server Faces 2.0 and Dynamic Web Library 3.0.

So currently I am getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor` in my `GenericDao` class
on

```
return (getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<T>()
    {
        @Override
        public T doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException
        { // The Error  
            Criteria executableCriteria = criteria.getExecutableCriteria(session); 
            return (T) executableCriteria.uniqueResult();
        }
    }));
```

Full strack trace...

```
    WARNING: #{loginBean.login}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginBean.login}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
    at org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(DetachedCriteria.java:84)
    at com.xx.hibernate.daos.GenericDao$3.doInHibernate(GenericDao.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:295)
    at com.xx.hibernate.daos.GenericDao.findUnique(GenericDao.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.findUnique(Unknown Source)
    at com.xx.services.UserService.findSalt(UserService.java:69)
    at com.xx.viewbeans.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 34 more

Mrz 25, 2014 9:48:30 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
    at org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(DetachedCriteria.java:84)
    at com.xx.hibernate.daos.GenericDao$3.doInHibernate(GenericDao.java:155)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:295)
    at com.xx.hibernate.daos.GenericDao.findUnique(GenericDao.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.findUnique(Unknown Source)
    at com.xx.services.UserService.findSalt(UserService.java:69)
    at com.xx.viewbeans.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 34 more
```

Furthermore, I have also been getting `NullPointerException`s on getting the hibernate template.

I have just converted the project to a maven project to have a better overview regarding the libraries. I can imagine that this issue is related to the libraries I am using...

Here is my pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.50</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
  <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
  <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
  <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0-RC2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
  <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a part of my applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation"
        value="classpath:com/xx/hibernate/mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="abstractDaoTarget" class="com.xx.hibernate.daos.GenericDao"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="abstractDao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
    abstract="true" />

<bean id="productDao" parent="abstractDao">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.xx.hibernate.daos.IProductDao" />
    <property name="target">
        <bean parent="abstractDaoTarget">
            <constructor-arg value="com.xx.hibernate.mappings.Product" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As an explanation, I am later on injecting these class specific daos into services. That was working fine with hibernate 3.

And a part of my `GenericDao` class...

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateCallback;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public class GenericDao<T> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IGenericDao<T>, Serializable {


@Override
public void delete(T obj)
{
    getHibernateTemplate().delete(obj);
}
```

Hibernate configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pw</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/xx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping resource="com/xx/hibernate/mappings/Battery.hbm.xml" />

        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

You guys would do me a huge favor, if you could help me out with this problem.

If you need to have a look at anything else, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have already updated every occurence of hibernate3 to hibernate4.

Comment: Do you have something in your configuration using or leading to proxies? I.e. some AOP stuff?  I want to note that it isn't recommended to use the `HibernateTemplate` anymore but just plain hibernate (since about Hibernate 3.0.1 in 2006!).

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is the ProxyFactoryBean in my applicationContext...What is the current recommmended method?

Comment: As I stated not using it and simply use a plain `SessionFactory` with `getCurrentSession()`. You also might want to consider moving to JPA and the usage of Spring Data JPA (which will probably allows you to remove your own custom generic dao implementation).

Comment: Currently rewriting a service to use `SessionFactory` with `getCurrentSession()`. I will post the solution, if I have one.

Comment: To make use of this it will also require proper tx setup (i.e add a `HibernateTransactionManager` and have a proper tx configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by M. Deinum, my source is completely outdated.

I rewrote the entire services and daos...

```
     BaseDao<T> implements IBaseDao<T>
    {

        private Class<T> type;

        public BaseDao()
        {

        }

        public BaseDao(Class<T> type)
        {
            this.type = type;
        }

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public void delete(T obj)
        {
            getSession().delete(obj);
        }

public Session getSession()
    {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        if (session == null)
        {
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }

        return session;
    }
    ...
```

My applicationContext...

```
<bean id="userDao" class="com.xx.hibernate.daos.UserDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>    

<bean id="userService" class="com.xx.services.UserService">
    <property name="dao" ref="userDao" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Furthermore, I have been using @Transactional annotation in my services.

I have also updated my c3p0 and eh-cache libraries to the latest hibernate versions.

Comment: Since this did not help me with the same issue, I opened a new question and got a very simple solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936931/classcastexception-proxy36-cannot-be-cast-to-sessionimplementor-after-hibernate