# ClassCastException Proxy36 cannot be cast to SessionImplementor after Hibernate/Spring 4 upgrade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, classcastexception

**EDIT: I am not asking *what* a ClassCastException is. I am asking what is causing it in DetachedCriteria under this specific configuration of Spring 4/Hibernate 4.**

I'm trying to upgrade some legacy code to Spring 4/Hibernate 4 and I've hit a wall, as Google isn't turning up much.

I am trying to run a JUnit test on a very simple Hibernate repository, and it is failing with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
    at org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(DetachedCriteria.java:84)
    at com.my.app.rest.domain.repository.AbstractHibernateRepository$6.doInHibernate(AbstractHibernateRepository.java:163)
...
```

This is happening in Hibernate's `org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria` class:

```
/**
 * Get an executable instance of Criteria to actually run the query.
 *
 * @param session The session to associate the built Criteria with
 *
 * @return The "executable" Criteria
 */
public Criteria getExecutableCriteria(Session session) {
    impl.setSession( (SessionImplementor) session );
    return impl;
}
```

When it tries to set the Session (which attempts to cast it to a SessionImplementor), it throws the ClassCastException.

I suspect this may be an AOP issue, but am not sure where to start looking.

I'm using Spring `4.3.2.RELEASE`, and Hibernate `4.3.5.Final`.

hibernate-context.xml:

```
    <bean id="xxxSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="xxxDataSource" />

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>hibernate/xxxUploadDocResponseInfo.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${xxx.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${xxx.hibernate.showsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${xxx.hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">${xxx.hibernate.formatsql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    <alias name="xxxSessionFactory" alias="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

transaction-context.xml:

```
<bean id="xxxTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="xxxTxAdvice" transaction-manager="xxxDatasourceTransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <!-- all methods begin with save have the transaction -->
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="remove*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="inactivate*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="complete*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="reset*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="flag*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="doWork*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean id="xxxDatasourceTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="xxxDataSource" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="allBusiness" expression="execution(public * com.blah.xxx.rest.business.*Business.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="xxxTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="allBusiness"/>
</aop:config>
```

AbstractHibernateRepository.java:

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateRepository<E extends Entity, S extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSupport {
...
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected E get(final DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria) {
    return (E) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<E>() {

        public E doInHibernate(Session session) {

            Criteria criteria = detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session);
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
            return (E) criteria.uniqueResult();
        }
    });
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [HibernateTemplate#doExecute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.html#doExecute-org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateCallback-boolean-)

> `enforceNativeSession` - whether to enforce exposure of the native Hibernate Session to callback code

As you can see at [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.java#HibernateTemplate.createSessionProxy%28org.hibernate.Session%29):

> ```
> protected Session createSessionProxy(Session session) {
>     return (Session) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
>     session.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] {Session.class},
>     new CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler(session));
> }
> ```

the created proxy implements only the interface `Session` not the interface `SessionImplementor`.

You have to replace [HibernateTemplate#execute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateCallback-) with [HibernateTemplate#executeWithNativeSession](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.html#executeWithNativeSession-org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateCallback-).

Comment: Amazing. I knew it had to be a one-liner. Thanks so much for your patience.

Answer (score 6):

Faced same issue on legacy code after upgrade to spring boot 2.4.0. Fixed by using `entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class)` to retrieve the session to be used for DetachedCriteria in my scenario.

Comment: Thank you. It worked on Spring Boot 2.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone having this issue with `FullTextEntityManager`, the answer from @Gardella works, however, this [link](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26090) suggests to update the Hibernate Search ORM dependency to 5.11.6.Final, which also resolves the issue.